# How can I open a file in java without its contents been removed?

Tags: java, file, io, java-io, formatter

I want my program to create a file for the user (just for the first time) and write some information to it (it's not just a line and also can be adjusted anytime later). So I did this:

```
public void write() {
    try {
        file = new File("c:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\text.txt");
        
        if(!file.exists())            // I found this somewhere on the internet for File class
            file.createNewFile();     // not to remove contents. I have no idea if it works
        
        writer = new Formatter(file);
    
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer.format("%s  %s ", nameInput.getText(),lastNameInput.getText());
    
    writer.close();
}
```

It works but there some problems:

1. When the file gets opened later, as default, the File class removes its contents.
2. When the information is written to the file and Formatter got closed, next time somewhere else in the program when I use it again to write to the file, the information gets updated and not added to the previous ones. And if I don't close it, it won't write.

Comment: Instead of passing `file` directly to `Formatter` constructor you can wrap it in `new FileWriter(f,true)` first where `true` enables append-mode and pass that writer. But aside from that, is there some specific reason you are using `Formatter` instead of more common `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` (both provide `format("format", data...)` method)?

Comment: @Pshemo yes i'm using formatter because i want to have information to be in a format that I want it to be,then i can read them using Scanner class. I know there are many other classes that are better be used here but I'm using these as a side of practicing. I'm a bit new to io concepts and I was thought to use these for simple writing and reading.

Comment: `found this somewhere on the internet` there is _one_ place you should look for the *definition* of how the Java runtime is supposed to work. As of 2021/06, make that the 16th edition of the [Java Standard Edition Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/), e.g., for [nio](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people mentioned above, I had to pass the file through the constructor of FileWriter class. this way my first problem got solved (I mentioned them in the question) and for the second one, I had to reopen the Formatter whenever I wanted to add more.

```
public void write() {

  try { 
    
    writer = new Formatter(new FileWriter(file,true);

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

writer.format("%s  %s ", nameInput.getText(),lastNameInput.getText());

writer.close();  }
```

creation and initialization of file should be done once and outside the method.

Comment: If you consulted the documentation, you should have noticed [void Formatter.flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#flush()).

Comment: (The initial revision of this answer doesn't point out exactly *what* in the code presented makes a difference with respect to the "File class not to remove contents". (`java.io.File` being a mis-named *path*, it is not surprising it [doesn't mess with file contents in any way](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#method.summary).))

Answer (score 1):

first af all, this code here:

```
if(!file.exists())            
        file.createNewFile();
```

it only creates a new file in case it doesn't exists in your path.

To write on your file without overwriting it I recommend you to do this:

```
FileWriter fileWriter;
public void write() {
try {
    file = new File("c:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\text.txt");

    if(!file.exists())            
        file.createNewFile();

    // use a FileWriter to take the file to write on 
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true); // true means that you do not overwrite the file
    writer = new Formatter(fileWriter); // than you put your FileWriter in the Formatter

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

writer.format("%s  %s ", nameInput.getText(),lastNameInput.getText());

writer.close();
}
```

Hope this was helpfull! :)

Comment: `true means that you overwrite the file` it is actually opposite... Nothing will be overwritten, instead new content will be appended. Aside from that `FileWriter fileWriter;` shouldn't probably be a field but a local variable.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks to both of you, my problem is solved.